# Why does type of braced-init-list with one element get switched to the type of the element itself?

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, type-traits, list-initialization

In the code below, the call to member function F of instance b with argument {1,2} compiles and calls `B::F(std::initializer_list<int>)`. But if I remove one element from the braced-init-list and use just {1}, I get an error

`9 : error: no matching function for call to 'begin(int)'
using type = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()));`

I don't understand why the compiler is looking for `begin(int)`, and not `begin(initializer_list<int>)`

I've been playing with this at https://godbolt.org/g/tMyYQs, and I get the same sort of error on both clang and g++. What am I missing?

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iterator>

template< bool B, class T = void >
using enable_if_t = typename std::enable_if<B,T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct mytrait {
  using type = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()));
  };

template <typename T>
class A {
  public:
  template <typename TA, typename =
     enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, typename mytrait<TA>::type>::value>>
      A(TA &&){}
};

class B
{
  public:
    void F(A<int>);
    void F(std::initializer_list<int>);
};

int main()
{
  B b;

  b.F({1,2});    // compiles fine
#if 0
  b.F({1});      // causes mytrait<int>::type to be examined, 
                 // not mytrait<std::initializer_list<int>>::type
#endif 
}
```

Comment: Because of "uniform initialization" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I think I figured it out. When the compiler sees `b.F({1})` it tries to figure out which overload of F to call. It sees that there is an overload that takes an `A<int>`, so, via [copy-list-initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization), it tries to see if it can construct an `A<int>` using `A<int>{1}`. The type of the literal `1` is int. So TA gets deduced to be int. `mytrait<int>` tries to determine `decltype(std::begin(declval<int>()))`, there's no std::begin for type int, so the compiler errors.

For `b.F({1,2})`, there's no constructor of `A<int>` that accepts two inputs, so list-initialization isn't even attempted.

It looks like I can fix this by changing my mytraits template declaration to

```
template <typename T, typename = decltype(std::begin(std::declval<T>()))>
struct mytraits {...};
```

That seems to be using SFINAE to make mytrait<int>::type be a substitution failure.